# Nib not a directory error when building project

Tags: ios, swift

I have the strangest issue with one of my Xib files. I have an XIB file called MyViewController.xib. This xib file very simple contains a view controller with a scroll view in it. When I run the project, I keep getting the following error:

```
cp: PathToProject/MyViewController.nib: Not a directory
Command /bin/sh emitted errors but did not return a nonzero exit code to indicate failure
```

Any ideas as to why I would be getting this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would occur when using Carthage. when building and coping a framework across to another projects Carthage folder these sort of errors would occur ever so often. The trick is to simply just delete the nib in the framework that is being copied to a given Carthage folder. Then do another build of the framework and all should work.

Answer (score 0):

Just delete the current reference to the file in your Xcode project then right click on the package you want to add the file to and select *Add files to "your_project_name"* and choose your file.

Answer (score 0):

[make Sure Your Project target.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jDG4J.png)